# Better way to return boolean

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wrote this wanting to match if a string matched a string inside an array. using find() it returned the match but I just wanted a boolean so i wrote an if statement. Any tips or hints on how to rewrite this cleaner to get a boolean?

the prop watchName comes from a map() of data of watches in inventory

```
.map(watch => (
            <WatchItem
              isInCart={this.isInCart(watch.name)}
.....
```

.

```
isInCart = watchName => {
  const hasMatch = this.props.cart.find(watch => watch.item === watchName);
  if (hasMatch) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};
```

To get better idea of whats inside this.props.cart i added it below
It is an array of objects. The picture shows index[0] and index[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2cM0.png) the added cart item

[image: picture of this.props.cart]

I will read mdn docs again but thought be good to post in case someone can quickly answer. 
Advice appreciated.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Comment: It might be worth considering that the cart should be modified here, not the item.

Comment: @Katie.Sun OP isn't trying to "modify" anything, though.

Comment: @CertainPerformance just trying to say that it might not be the greatest design to have an `isInCart` boolean attached to an object. Just add it to the cart, and search the cart for the items

Comment: Why don't you set isInCart when it gets added to the cart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return it directly. Use a double negation `!!` or just wrap it inside `Boolean`.

```
isInCart = watchName => 
  !!this.props.cart.find(watch => watch.item === watchName);
```

either

```
isInCart = watchName => 
  Boolean(this.props.cart.find(watch => watch.item === watchName));
```

Comment: oohhh yes I seen that before but forgot thank you. Woo

Comment: Also very useful if the underlying return value from find is ever used; where as some will not provide that result

Comment: Well the 2nd one fails let's say if value it self is 0

Comment: @CodeManiac Which value can evaluate to 0?

Comment: Find returns the value and he's checking whether the value is there in array or not

Comment: @CodeManiac He is looping over an array of objects. There's no chance that it will return 0.

Comment: @kinduser oh sorry for the miss. you're right in case of objects. I was thinking more generic way.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Array.prototype.some` instead, which checks whether any element in an array satisfies a condition, and returns a *boolean*:

```
isInCart = watchName => this.props.cart.some(watch => watch.item === watchName);
```

Comment: While this is also an acceptable answer it is different that the logic which is used in the OPS question; hence the reason I did not vote for this answer; The big difference is that the only result you can ever expect from some is the Boolean.

Comment: Thanks for reply I will that that I never used some before.

Comment: @Jay That's what OP is looking for, though, right? OP *wants* to only have a Boolean, he doesn't want the matching item (that's the whole reason for the question), or did I misinterpret something? `isInCart` isn't `findWatchInCart`

Comment: Not in my humble opinion; your change results in a change to the result of the underlying expression where at the solution above does not do that; hence I lose the instance which I have spent the cycles finding.

Comment: @Jay Can you show me how the logic is different? I'm looking at it but I don't see where there might be a difference, both this and OP's code should return `true` if a matching item is found, and `false` otherwise

Comment: See mozilla developer network. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Answer (score 2):

**You can use this too**

```
  isInCart = watchName => this.props.cart.includes(watchName);
```